# How to save PHP code written in Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using Artisteer to create WordPress themes.
Artisteer is not able to include php code into pages, then I have to do some modification via WordPress page editor.

I'm using "PHP Insert" plugin to include php code into WordPress page editor and to make WordPress able to use my php code into my pages.

In my site I have a form for B.M.I. calculation and I need to use php code in the page.

The problem is that if I change the theme in Artisteer and if I upload it into WordPress, I loose php changes.
It's very boring to apply modification every time (and also dangerous...lost code, wrong code position,...).

I'm thinking to use a child theme, but I don't know how to apply it to php code added into pages.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wordpress team has made it a rule of thumb to *never* execute PHP in posts and pages either because it can be hectic to change things in the future and may expose security vulnerabilities that could not be fixed by Wordpress itself.

A better practice is editing your WordPress theme by creating a custom post/page template - that basically can include everything. However for some situations, it may be necessary to execute PHP on more than one WordPress posts/pages.

In this case, my recommendation would be to create a simple page template containing your PHP, or, if your code is used multiple times, create a shortcode (in the functions.php of your template).

Simplest example of adding a shortcode tag (with parameters) to your themes `functions.php`:

```
function footag_func( $atts ) {
     return "foo = {$atts['foo']}";
}
add_shortcode('footag', 'footag_func');
```

The output code can be used everywhere with the tag **[footag foo="bar"]**. When extending this, alway remember to `return` the results of your function. Using `echo` or `print` would just echo the results (on the top of your content, skipping the content itself).

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to use PHP in the content editor, you've got a few decent options:

- Creating a custom template for that specific page:
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates
- Creating a shortcode for that specific piece of PHP code:
  http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API